# plotting single (datum,column) from each block with lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, block

I have a data file containing constant-size blocks of data. In order to plot element (n,m) from each block I do

```
pl file u m ev ::n-1::n-1
```

This works fine, but the graph is displayed in point style since this is default for data. When I add "with lines" to the command above, this produces an empty graph.

Comment: are your blocks separated by a single empty line or by two or more empty lines?

Comment: single empty line and one comment line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are shorter solutions, but the first solution which comes to my mind is to plot the data into a datablock and then plot this datablock. This will remove empty lines and hence datapoints will be connected when plotting `with lines` or `with linespoints`.

**Code:**

```
### plot individual datapoints from each block with lines
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  11
2  12
3  13

4  14
5  15
6  16

7  17
8  18
9  19
EOD

m = 2
n = 1

set table $DataSelected
    plot $Data u m every ::n-1::n-1 w table
unset table

plot $DataSelected u 1 w linespoints pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]